# Compare dates in variables, check if they are in ascending orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 4 variables

```
@start_date                         date
@first_reminder_date                date
@second_reminder_date               date
@end_date                           date
```

I want to check if they are in ascending order. Also start_date should be greater than or equal to current date as well. I mean that it should satisfy the condition-

**`getdate() <=@start_date <=@first_reminder_date <=@second_reminder_date <=end_date`**

What is the most optimized way to do that?

**Note:All date variables can be null as well, that is a pass condition.
Variable type is date.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test what you have to. There are no really most optimized way with such simple tests:

```
if ((getdate() <= @start_date or @start_date is null)
    and (@start_date <= @first_reminder_date or @first_reminder_date is null)
    and (@first_reminder_date <= @second_reminder_date or @second_reminder_date is null)
    and (@second_reminder_date <= @end_date or @end_date is null)) then Begin ascending... End else Begin descending... End
```

Comment: Thanks Julien for the answer, I wrote the same thing. it might be more expensive and stupid but I was thinking on the lines of putting them in a table and comparing the table to a ordered table.

Comment: You can join on whatever is needed and then replace variable names by column name and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I meant. Anyway I will put is null check before date compare to optimize it a little :)
Thanks Again.